# Installing osixia/docker-openldap using docker-compose

Tags: php, symfony, docker, openldap, docker-compose

I do know why this won't work with docker-compose, even after I use osixia/openldap:1.0.2.

here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
...
openldap:
image: osixia/openldap:1.0.2
ports:
- "389:389"
environment:
- LDAP_ORGANISATION=myorg
- LDAP_DOMAIN=myorg.com.au
- LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
```

the problem is it keep stuck/stop at "Pulling repository docker.io/osixia/openldap" for about 1 hour, here is the detail :

```
Pulling openldap (osixia/openldap:1.0.2)...
1.0.2: Pulling from osixia/openldap
f4035ccd552a: Pull complete
09e853d45374: Pull complete
1887be597057: Pull complete
b36790f4fd7c: Pull complete
307c8081e6ee: Pull complete
a69db075c744: Pulling fs layer
caaf8d37abdb: Download complete
52769789ae54: Pulling fs layer
d2be0405195d: Download complete
0c65abd21d4f: Download complete
cfbcb41a5d50: Download complete
9a7f68422403: Pulling fs layer
3627a08de6df: Pulling fs layer
3627a08de6df: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting.
9a61b6b1315e: Already exists
Pulling repository docker.io/osixia/openldap
```

any suggestions for this ?
thank

Comment: There's a bug in docker where pulls can get stuck.  I'd suggest restarting docker and then it should work.

Comment: yes, I have restarted the docker service and it's work nice now.. :)

Comment: hi it will be nice if you put your comment as answer so I can vote it as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

"There's a bug in docker where pulls can get stuck. I'd suggest restarting docker and then it should work."

- [answer submitted by @dnephin, Oct 20 2015 at 19:35](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206237/installing-osixia-docker-openldap-using-docker-compose/71129936#comment54292907_33206237)